# With IntelliJ, how can I get a view with two projects, one not being a Maven project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have two projects. Let's call them MavenProject and NotMavenProject.

The structure is like this

- repo/mavenProject
- repo/notMavenProject

If both were Maven projects and had a parent POM, I would simply make a project import based on that and everything would be fine. However, the notMavenProject does not have its own POM, and the two projects do not have a parent POM.

The only POM in the folder is repo/mavenProject/pom.xml

IntelliJ seems incapable of simply giving me a view that would look similar to what it would have if both were Maven projects - one folder per view, and the ability to easily compile each module.

I can mark directories as source root, however, I cannot "mark as module" or something like that.

Can I not simply import a folder, where some sub-folders are Maven projects and some aren't?

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking the pom.xml gives me the "mark as module" option I was looking for.